# Getting SSLHandshakeException when using Dropbox Java SDK for API v2

Tags: java, jvm, lotus-domino, dropbox-api, jsse

In a **XPages** application I want to make use of the **Dropbox Java SDK (2.1.2) for API v2** to get information about my Dropbox account. The following code is used to retrieve the corresponding account object:

```
String atoken = "****";
DbxRequestConfig rc = new DbxRequestConfig("****");
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(rc,atoken);
DbxUserUsersRequests users = client.users();
FullAccount acc = users.getCurrentAccount(); // Exception raised here
```

The last line raises the following exception:

```
com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException: No appropriate protocol 
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:240)
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol 
at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.c(kb.java:347)
...
```

From the stacktrace I concluded that **IBMJSSE2** is the security provider used to handle the SSL handshake. So I ran the code from above in a non-Domino JVM (JRE7) which uses the **SunJSSE** security provider and it worked without any problems. Hence the problem must be related to IBM's Domino JVM but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can anybody help me with this or provide a hint to a solution?

---

**Additional information**:

Version of Domino server: **9.0.1 FP4 HF70**

Java runtime version: pwa6460sr16fp4-20150414_01 (SR16 FP4) [22B8:0002-1E88]

JVM version: **JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4** Windows 7 amd64-64 jvmwa6460sr16fp4-20150406_242976 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) J9VM - 20150406_242976 JIT - r9_20150402_88984 GC - GA24_Java6_SR16_20150406_1410_B242976

Unrestricted JCE policy files have been installed in the Domino JVM.

Properties of the **IBMJSSE2** security provider:

```
Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.IbmPKIX = PKIX
Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.X.509 = PKIX
Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.X509 = PKIX
KeyManagerFactory.IbmX509 = com.ibm.jsse2.rc$a_
KeyManagerFactory.NewIbmX509 = com.ibm.jsse2.rc$b_
Provider.id className = com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
Provider.id info = IBM JSSE provider2 (implements IbmX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
Provider.id name = IBMJSSE2
Provider.id version = 1.6
SSLContext.Default = com.ibm.jsse2.tc
SSLContext.SSL = com.ibm.jsse2.uc
SSLContext.SSL_TLS = com.ibm.jsse2.vc
SSLContext.SSL_TLSv2 = com.ibm.jsse2.wc
SSLContext.TLS = com.ibm.jsse2.yc
SSLContext.TLSv1 = com.ibm.jsse2.zc
SSLContext.TLSv1.1 = com.ibm.jsse2.ad
SSLContext.TLSv1.2 = com.ibm.jsse2.bd
TrustManagerFactory.IbmX509 = com.ibm.jsse2.ed$b_
TrustManagerFactory.PKIX = com.ibm.jsse2.ed$a_
```

Full stacktrace of exception:

```
com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException: No appropriate protocol 
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:240) 
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:100) 
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:256) 
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:97) 
at com.dropbox.core.v2.users.DbxUserUsersRequests.getCurrentAccount(DbxUserUsersRequests.java:120) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:280) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:219) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171) 
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionPrototype$FunctionMethod.call(FunctionPrototype.java:169) 
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) 
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:448) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251) 
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234) 
at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222) 
at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111) 
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokePhaseMethodBinding(UIViewRootEx.java:1735) 
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.invokePhaseMethodBinding(FacesControllerImpl.java:450) 
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.access$0(FacesControllerImpl.java:444) 
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl$ViewPhaseListener.afterPhase(FacesControllerImpl.java:512) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:218) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120) 
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270) 
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261) 
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157) 
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160) 
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138) 
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576) 
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565) 
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319) 
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662) 
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357) 
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313) 
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272) 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol 
at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.c(kb.java:347) 
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.i(SSLSocketImpl.java:363) 
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:650) 
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:669) 
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:95) 
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:162) 
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:36) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1044) 
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:53) 
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.getOutputStream(StandardHttpRequestor.java:123) 
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.access$000(StandardHttpRequestor.java:28) 
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor$Uploader.(StandardHttpRequestor.java:133) 
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:72) 
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:28) 
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:232)
...
```

---

**Update**: After setting `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data` (as suggested by Jigar Joshi) the error log and trace log provide the following additional information:

Certificate with subject EMAILADDRESS=****, CN=****, O=****, L=****, ST=****, C=****, issued by CN=****, OU=****, O=****, C=****, **is not trusted. Validation failed with error 3659**.

```
CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName = com.ibm.domino.napi.ssl.DominoX509TrustManager
CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName = checkServerTrusted
<sourcecomponentid component="Expeditor 6.2" componentidtype="ProductName" instanceid="" location="****" locationtype="Hostname" subcomponent="com.ibm.domino.napi.ssl" threadid="5" componenttype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

The certificate that is not trusted is **my own**, even though all certificates and the private key were imported into my keystore. The fact that the keystore works in the non-Domino JVM allows me to conclude that the keystore file should be valid. Yet, the certificate is still not trusted when running the code in the Domino JVM.

---

**Update**: The core part of the debug output (`javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`) is

```
SSLContextImpl:  Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.hd
SSLContextImpl:  Using X509TrustManager com.ibm.jsse2.pc
IBMJSSE2 will ignore com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol since was set to a non recognized value TLSv1
Installed Providers = IBMJSSE2, IBMJCE, IBMJGSSProvider, IBMCertPath, IBMSASL, IBMXMLCRYPTO, IBMXMLEnc, Policy, IBMSPNEGO
JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom IBMSecureRandom from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
IBMJSSE2 will enable CBC protection
IBMJSSE2 to send SCSV Cipher Suite on initial ClientHello
JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom IBMSecureRandom from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default
IBMJSSE2 will not require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken
IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert check during renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default
IBMJSSE2 will not allow unsafe server certificate change during renegotiation per jdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange set to FALSE or default
Is initial handshake: true
JsseJCE:  Using KeyAgreement ECDH from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA1withECDSA from provider TBD via init 
JsseJCE:  Using signature NONEwithECDSA from provider TBD via init 
JsseJCE:  Using KeyFactory EC from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator EC from provider TBD via init 
JsseJce:  EC is available
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RENEGO_PROTECTION_REQUEST for TLSv1
No available cipher suite for TLSv1
Thread-8, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol
Thread-8, SEND TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, 
description = handshake_failure
```

"**No available cipher suite for TLSv1**" seems to be the root of my problem.

---

**Update**: Getting the default SSL server socket factory (`SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()`) and the corresponding default and supported cipher suites (`getDefaultCipherSuites()` / `getSupportedCipherSuites()`) revealed that only SSL cipher suites are available:

```
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5 [supported]
SSL_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA [supported]
SSL_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 [supported]
SSL_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 [supported]
SSL_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA [supported]
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 [supported]
SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA [default]
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 [supported]
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA [supported]
```

**Can anybody tell me how to make TLS cipher suites available in the server socket factory?**

Comment: enable ssl debugging and post the log around the handshake `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data`

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Thanks for the advice. The error log now says that the "Certificate ... is not trusted. Validation failed with error 3659.". I will do some google research on that error but I'd of course be grateful if you have more tips on how to tackle the problem :)

Comment: Can you paste the URL where you are attempting to make SSL connection if it is public ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: [1] My source url is not public (I'm running the application locally on my computer). [2] I don't exactly know the target urls the Dropbox Java SDK connects to, but it should be the user endpoints of the HTTP API, i.e. https://api.dropboxapi.com/... . [3] I think I found a solution to the problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/505273/java-certificateexception-in-domino-9-when-trying-to-access-https-url. I will report back here as soon as I have tried the suggested steps.

Comment: For PKIX exception with java, install certificate into jre cacerts. detailed guide is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40757655/1802348).

Comment: @jaydeep: Thanks for the tip. The certificate that is not trusted is my own and not the certificate of the destination (Dropbox). I forgot to add that to the text and will correct it. Also, the root certificates of my CA as well as the Dropbox CA have both been imported into the truststore (cacerts).

Comment: @JigarJoshi: The output from `javax.net.debug` and some more debugging revealed that the SSLServerSocketFactory only contains cipher suites for SSL, but not for TLS (see information added to the question). Do you happen to know how to make TLS cipher suites available in the socket factory?

Comment: what version of JVM you are using ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: The JVM version is JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4

Comment: The IBM cipher suites should now be supported in the Dropbox Java SDK as of v3.0.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the Dropbox Java SDK [limits the enabled cipher suites](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/http/SSLConfig.java#L159) in the SSL sockets based on a hard-coded list. All relevant cipher suite names in [that list](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/http/SSLConfig.java#L78) start with "**TLS_**". However, in the Domino JVM cipher suite names always start with "**SSL_**" even when the SSL context they are related to has protocol TLSv1 or higher.

I have now stopped working with the Dropbox Java SDK and started using the Dropbox API by making HTTP posts using [HttpsUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html). This is not as convenient as the Java SDK, but at least the SSL handshake with TLSv1 works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Re

```
com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException: No appropriate protocol
```

My best guess is that this line is a strong hint of your problem:

```
Provider.id info = IBM JSSE provider2 (implements IbmX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
```

"No appropriate protocol" sounds like it's probably telling you that the endpoint doesn't support SSLv3 or TLSv1.

I don't know about Dropbox, but many service providers are deprecating those older protocols due to known security problems.

You may find some useful info in [these two](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21697925) [IBM technotes](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688165).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first I also believed that the missing support of TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 was the problem, but for the following reasons I think (not know) that this is not the case: [1] The Java SDK should work with Java 6+ which natively does not support any TLS > v1. [2] The security provider in the non-Domino JVM is "Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)" and does not seem to support higher TLS versions the IBMJSSE2 either. [3] I did set "https.protocols=TLSv1" in the non-Domino JVM to have the same TLS version as in the Domino JVM.

Comment: I forgot to post the link from the Dropbox documentation which clearly states that TLSv1.0 is supported ("...Requiring TLS v1.0 and above..."): https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/http/SSLConfig.html